# Project Euler #8 in C++: greatest product of k consecutive digits

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

This a problem from [Hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler008) and [Project Euler #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8). The problem statement is as below. Is there a specific algorithm to solve such problems? Can my code be made more efficient?

---

> Find the greatest product of `K` consecutive digits in the `N` digit
>   number.
>
> **Input Format:** First line contains `T` that denotes the number of test cases.  First line of each test case will contain two integers
>   `N` & `K`. Second line of each test case will contain an `N` digit
>   integer.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the required answer for each test case.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> \$1 \le T \le 1000\$
>
> \$1 \le K \le 7\$
>
> \$K \le N \le 1000\$

---

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define ctoi(c)(int)((c)-'0')

inline unsigned long long prodK(string number, int start, int end){
    unsigned long long product=1;
    for (int j=start;j<end;j++){
        product*=ctoi(number[j]);
    }
    return product;
}

int main() {
    int T,N,K;
    string number;
    unsigned long long product,max;
    cin>>T;
    for (int i=0;i<T;i++){
        cin>>N>>K;
        cin>>number;
        product=1;
        product=prodK(number,0,K);
        max=product;
        for (int l=K;l<N;l++){
            if (ctoi(number[l-K])!=0){
                product=(product/ctoi(number[l-K]))*ctoi(number[l]);
            }else{
                product=prodK(number,l-K+1,l+1);
            }
            max=(product>max)?product:max;
        }
        cout<<max<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Extra multiplication

> ```
>     unsigned long long product=1;
>     for (int j=start;j<end;j++){
>         product*=ctoi(number[j]);
>     }
> ```

You can do one less multiplication.

```
    unsigned long long product = ctoi(number[j]);
    for (int j = start + 1; j < end; j++) {
        product *= ctoi(number[j]);
    }
```

Obviously this would fail if `K` were less than 1, but that's outside the problem scope.

#### `ctoi` is not a free operation

You also perform `ctoi` at least `K` times for each digit.  You could do this just once with something like

```
    std::vector<int> digits;
    for (char c : number) {
        digits.push_back((int)(c - '0');
    }
```

Then operate on `digits` rather than `number`.

#### Benchmark optimizations

> ```
>             if (ctoi(number[l-K])!=0){
>                 product=(product/ctoi(number[l-K]))*ctoi(number[l]);
>             }else{
>                 product=prodK(number,l-K+1,l+1);
>             }
> ```

In theory, this saves `K-1` multiplications at the cost of doing a multiplication, a division, and a comparison/branch.  But don't forget that it adds a comparison/branch to every iteration.  You might find that is cheaper to always do the `K-1` multiplications.

Benchmark it both ways with a variety of inputs to see.

#### Don't waste math

You have

> ```
>     for (int j=start;j<end;j++){
> ```

and

> ```
>                     product=prodK(number,l-K+1,l+1);
> ```

But you could just have

> ```
>     for (int j = start; j <= end; j++){
> ```

and

```
                    product = prodK(number, l-K+1, l);
```

That saves you an addition.  Might not be worth much, but it also might be better than nothing.

#### Assignments can be expensive

> ```
>             max=(product>max)?product:max;
> ```

This will produce the correct answer, but it does an assignment every time.  You don't need to do the no-op assignment.  Benchmark against

```
            if (product > max) {
                max = product;
            }
```

That's more code, but it's faster unless the compiler already optimizes out the no-op assignment.  Probably not a lot faster, as this is a comparatively simple assignment.

#### Simplify compare

> ```
>     for (int i=0;i<T;i++){
> ```

`i<T` is often implemented as `i - T < 0`.  But do you need to do the `i - T`?

Since you never use `T` for anything other than this loop, you could say

```
    for (; T > 0; T--) {
```

That saves having an `i` variable at all, and now you compare `T` to 0 directly.

#### Benchmark

These are suggestions that assume that the compiler is operating in a certain way.  If I'm wrong about that, then some of these suggestions may be counterproductive.  Note that the compiler may have similar or better optimizations that it is already doing.  You benchmark to confirm (or refute) such assumptions.

Comment: I wonder if, for a slight bit of optimization, you can check the sum instead of the product and multiply only if the sum exceeds the maximum sum. For large numbers, this may be slightly faster?

Comment: Thank you. This is good insight. I shall try to implement your suggestions and benchmark.

Comment: @mdfst - will the compiler with -o3 not do things like - `for (; T > 0; T--)` while generating the binary executable?